# shell scripting with expect and a complex command line: no such file or directory

Tags: shell-scripting, expect

I'm trying to make this work

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "(psql blabla \"blabla sql;\" &> /dev/null) && (pg_restore -d xx my_file.sql &> /dev/null)"

expect "Password for user my_base: "
send "v"
```

But I always get:

```
spawn (psql blabla "blabla sql;" &> /dev/null) && (pg_restore -d xx my_file.sql &> /dev/null)
couldn't execute "(psql blabla "blabla sql;" &> /dev/null) && (pg_restore -d xx my_file.sql &> /dev/null)": no such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) don't put the `spawn` arguments in quotes, and 2) spawn doesn't understand shell syntax, you need to explicitly spawn a shell

```
spawn bash -c {(psql blabla "blabla sql;" &> /dev/null) && (pg_restore -d xx my_file.sql &> /dev/null)}
```

This uses braces, which are the expect/Tcl equivalent of shell's single quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. I have to learn: `C#`, `JavaScript`, `HTML`, `CSS`, `Python`, `Django`, `docker`, `kubernetes`, not to talk about `git` and all this "months learning curve", and now `shell`............................ so I feel "a bit" overwhelmed....

Comment: not to mention `expect` which does have a fairly steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not really the answer to your question, but if you're trying to do a `pg_restore` without entering a password, you can also use the `~/.pgpass` file to store credentials in.

Postgres documentation on `~/.pgpass` -

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html